# How does concavity imply that the marginal utility of a gain is less than the difference between utilities?

Tags: microeconomics, utility

Considerin turning down a 50-50 gamble of losing \$ 10 and gaining \$ 11 at wealth w.

$1/2*u(w-10)+1/2*u(w+11)≤u(w)$

Concavity implies that $u'(w+11)*11≤u(w+11)-u(w)$ and
$u(w)-u(w-10)≤u'(w-10)*10$

From this we arrive to the result that $u'(w+11)*11≤u'(w-10)*10$

I don't understand what does the marginal utility of $u'(w+11)$ need to be multipltied by 11. Is it like saying the rate of increase multiplied by the increase? Also, how do we know that this is going to be less than u(w+11)-u(w)? Is it solely from the assumption of concavity?

Comment: please use `\ ` in front of dollar sign if you are not writing equations otherwise the text gets messed up. Also, please show us your attempt firsts, per our rules for self-study questions